# iptables - port ward and NAT destination address

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, nat

I have a server running strongswan. I have two clients connecting to this server over IPSec. My encryption domain is 10.1.1.3/32 which is the real address of the server. However, client A wants my encryption domain to be a public ip, so I provide them with a public ip of 1.2.3.4/32. Using iptables, I NAT 1.2.3.4/32 to 10.1.1.3/32. My application is running on port 1117. All is good. Now I have a new version of the application, and I run it on port 1118. I want to test this application, and to do this, I added a port forwarding rule like so

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 10.10.10.0/24 --dport 117 -j REDIRECT --to-port 118
```

This is for Clinet B, who is connected with an IP address in the range 10.10.10.0/24. This worked perfectly. However, when I added a similar rule to clinet A, it is not working; the packets are still going to port 117. Here is the rule for Clinet A.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 165.121.113.217/32 --dport 117 -j REDIRECT --to-port 118
```

I see the rules when I execute

```
sudo iptables -t nat --line-numbers -L PREROUTING
```

The difference between the two clients is that Clinet A has NAT rule in place. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: for client A you did `... --dport 117 -j REDIRECT --to-port 118` ... note the numbers are not the same as `--dport 1117 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1118`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, i corrected it. They are all 1117 and 1118. thanks.

Comment: you corrected the wrong one in the question then, because now your question shows 117/118 for both

Comment: `so I provide them with a public ip of 1.2.3.4/32. Using iptables, I NAT 1.2.3.4/32 to 10.1.1.3/32`  Not really getting the sense here. You mean like there's another "jump host" with the public IP `1.2.3.4/32`, and client A is accessing it directly via its ISP (or at least, no "private VPN" between the client and `10.1.1.3`), or, is client A also connected to the server with a VPN like client B is, but just that its VPN subnet is not `10.10.10.0/24`, and the server is effectively client A's default gateway? If it's the latter case, what's the VPN subnet used for the server and client A?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Both A and B are connecting to my server through an IPSec VPN. A and B both are hospitals, and we are just a S/W vendor to them. Our server is not the default gateway.

Comment: Then how is it supposed to reach the server with a public IP (let alone whether there's a point)? Is the client configured with a host route specifically for that public IP (which routes the traffics into the tunnel)? Why would you expect the source IP to be not its VPN IP anyway?

Comment: Following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAdJojxENEU helped me solve my issue. Instead of doing a DNAT and then a redirect, I simply did a DNAT and added the destination port to the DNAT IP solved my issue.

Comment: Thinking through this, I think I know what happened. I had two rules in the PREROUTING chain. one for DNAT and the other for REDIRECT, for the same packet. So the first rule was applied and skipped the second rule.